# How to print a value from array by filter?

Tags: javascript

I have a simple array I need to print the number which matches the value.

```
array = {'plana':'1', 'planb':'2', 'planc': '3'};

value = "plana";

output = 1
```

Maybe something like this

```
array.filter(obj => obj == value);
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 2):

What you have is an object. You cannot filter objects like an array. What you need is to convert the object into an array and then filter it.

The following example solution is for filter since you explicitly asked.

```js
const array = {'plana':'1', 'planb':'2', 'planc': '3'};
const result = Object.keys(array).map(function(key) {
  return [key, array[key]];
});
 
const value = "plana";
const filteredItem = result.filter(item => item[0] === value);

console.log(filteredItem[0][1])
```

**You can achieve this without filter**

```js
const array = {'plana':'1', 'planb':'2', 'planc': '3'};
const value = "plana";

console.log(array[value])
```